# Código a funcionar a determinada hora

Tags: javascript

Eu gostaria de saber como coloco para um código estar ativo entre determinadas horas, que neste caso seria entre as 7h e as 22h do fuso horário Brasília.

Tentei estudar este que já contém essa função, pórem não entendi:

```
          var horaAtual = (new Date()).getHours();
          var imagem = "";
          if(horaAtual >= horario_inicio["manhã"] && horaAtual < horario_inicio

["tarde"]){
              imagem = imagens["manhã"];
          }else if(horaAtual >= horario_inicio["tarde"] && horaAtual < 

horario_inicio["noite"]){
              imagen = imagens["tarde"];
          }else if(horaAtual >= horario_inicio["noite"] || horaAtual < horario_inicio

["manhã"]){
              imagen = imagens["noite"];
          }

          if(imagem_se_repete){
              jQuery(seletor_css).css("background", "url(" + imagem + ") repeat");
          }else{
              jQuery(seletor_css).css({"background-image":"url(" + imagem + ")", 

"background-repeat":"no-repeat", "background-size":"cover"}); 
          }
    });
```

O código em que quero colocar horário de funcionamento é o seguinte:

```
$(function() {
$(".post").each(function() {
    if (_userdata.user_level == 2 || _userdata.user_level == 1) {
    return;
    }
if($('.pathname-box:contains(Tarefas), .pathname-box:contains(Redações)').length > 0) {
    var username = _userdata.username;
    if ($(this).has('.staff').length) {
    return;
  }
    if($(this).html().indexOf(username) <= 1) {
          $(this).remove();
    }
    if($(this).html().indexOf(username) >= 1) {
          $(this).remove();
    }
}
    });
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Com Javascript ? É simples:

Peguei apenas as horas e verifiquei se ela se encaixa no horário citado, dentro do if é so colocar a função que você deseja executar.

**Exemplo 1:**

```js
var d = new Date();
var hora = d.getHours();
if (hora >= 7 && hora <= 22) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = hora + ' horario atual';
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Se você não sabe que horas são para executar a função, você pode usar `setInterval()` para chamar a sua função que valida o horario e faz o que você precisa.

**Exemplo 2:**

```js
function validaHorario() {
  var d = new Date();
  var hora = d.getHours();
  if (hora >= 7 && hora <= 22) {
    alert(hora + ' horario atual');
  }
}

setInterval(function() {
  validaHorario()
}, 298000); // executa a função validaHorario() de 5 em 5 min
```

Comment: Deu o seguinte erro: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list   / código que estou a utilizar: http://pastebin.com/sD7Y49Ef

Comment: Esta correto, só como o AP comentou ele gostaria no horário de brasília, e a função `getHours()` trabalha com a hora local. Ou seja pode haver discrepância, para isso deve se usar `getUTCHours()` que retorna o hora universal, contudo para isso o AP tera que levar em consideração esta diferença em seu horaria também.

Comment: @MaradinhoPH o problema esta no seu console.log você esta passando string sem aspas e não esta concatenando

Comment: ops! não reparei nesse pormenor. tudo okay! obrigado.