# Código definido para funcionar a determinada hora

Tags: javascript

Eu possuo um código que deveria funcionar a determinada hora, porem ele não está funcionando.

```
$(function() {
    $(".post").each(function() {
        var d = new Date();
        var hora = d.getHours();
        if (hora <= 7 && hora >= 22) {
            alert("O código está funcionando!");
            if (_userdata.user_level == 2 || _userdata.user_level == 1) {
                return;
            }
            if ($('.pathname-box:contains(Tarefas), .pathname-box:contains(Redações)').length > 0) {
                var username = _userdata.username;
                if ($(this).has('.staff').length) {
                    return;
                }
                if ($(this).html().indexOf(username) <= 1) {
                    $(this).remove();
                }
                if ($(this).html().indexOf(username) >= 1) {
                    $(this).remove();
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Parte de definir a hora:

```
            var d = new Date();
            var hora = d.getHours();
            if (hora <= 7 && hora >= 22) {
```

**Observação:** Se eu retirar a parte em que define o horário em que o código deve funcionar, ele começa a funcionar por isso não pode ser problema do código.

Código sem horário:

```
$(function() {
    $(".post").each(function() {
            alert("O código está funcionando!");
            if (_userdata.user_level == 2 || _userdata.user_level == 1) {
                return;
            }
            if ($('.pathname-box:contains(Tarefas), .pathname-box:contains(Redações)').length > 0) {
                var username = _userdata.username;
                if ($(this).has('.staff').length) {
                    return;
                }
                if ($(this).html().indexOf(username) <= 1) {
                    $(this).remove();
                }
                if ($(this).html().indexOf(username) >= 1) {
                    $(this).remove();
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Essa condição `if (hora <= 7 && hora >= 22) {` é impossível. Qual é o numero que é ao mesmo tempo menor ou igual a sete e maior ou igual a 22? Será que queres usar o _ou_? ie: `||`

Comment: Era isso mesmo! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essa condição `if (hora <= 7 && hora >= 22) {` é impossível. Não existe nenhum numero que seja ao mesmo tempo menor ou igual a sete e maior ou igual a 22?

Acho que queres usar o operador  *ou*, ou seja: `||`

```
if (hora <= 7 || hora >= 22) {
```

E assim correr o código entre as zero horas e as 7 (inclusive) e mais tarde depois das dez da noite até ao fim do dia.

Comment: Mesmo assim continua sem funcionar, até coloquei um alert() para ver se surgia algo, mas nada.

Comment: Esqueça... funcionou sim! Eu havia colocado `|||` kkkkk. Muito obrigado amigo!

Comment: Ótimo! fico contente de ter ajudado.

Comment: Se você quer que execute entre as 7hrs á 22hrs  a condição que você precisa é: if (hora >= 7 && hora <= 22), vi que no seu código você não seguiu a resposta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/92564/c%C3%B3digo-a-funcionar-a-determinada-hora

Comment: Como pode ver, é como estava anteriormente. Mas não estava a funcionar.